# MSAL owin single signon

Tags: owin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have few existing application which uses OWIN (cookie based) AAD convergence model, using which we were able to provide single sign on experience,

currently we are on boarding a new SPA application written using MSAL js and would like to provide the same single sign on experience.

Note: MSAL based SPA application used access-token to retrieve information from webapi. Moving from MSAL to OWIN would not work as the accestoken would not be available at client side.

Please let us know if there is any suggested approach to achieve SSO between OWIN and MSAL.